# How to suppress python output to screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout, open3d

I am using python.

The following line of code prints some information to the screen:

`p = open3d.read_point_cloud("data.ply")`,

which prints `Reading PLY: [========================================] 100%`

I want to suppress the printed information.

I tried this:

```
text_trap = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = text_trap

p = open3d.read_point_cloud("data.ply")

sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

However it does not work. I found the implementation of this function to be inside a `.so` file.

Can anyone provide help? Appreciate it!

Comment: The documentation for this function at http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.io.read_point_cloud.html tells you it has an optional boolean parameter `print_progress` that does what you want. I found that as the first Google hit for `open3d.read_point_cloud`.  Next time do a little research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to add this as a comment but, I don't have enough rep to add comments, so Typing it as a answer.

Have you tried to use the print_progress parameter, this might solve your problem

`p = open3d.read_point_cloud("data.ply",print_progress=False)`

Comment: ok? it was not loaded for me , so what? i left the page open and was trying to figure out a way to comment and later came to a conclusion that i just wont be able to make comments to that question @martineau

Comment: Thank you. Actually I am using the 0.7.0 version of open3d, which does not have an argument called `print_progress`. I found that starting from 0.8.0, this argument is added and is set to false by default. So I managed to switched to 0.8.0. Anyway, your answer helps solve my problem!

Comment: @martineau what's your problem, why are you being like this to me ?